# React Redux- Timeout before Store Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on getting animations with anime js into my react redux app. I have a notifications objects in the store, and when the user clicks delete a notification is deleted, and the store updates. However, I need to wait a couple hundred milliseconds to let the fade-out animation to play. I tried setting a time out before calling the action, with no luck.

```
handleDeleteNoti = notification => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        anime({
        targets: this.notiRef,
        opacity: [1,0],
        duration: 5000,
        })
    }, 5000);
    this.props.clearNotification(notification._id);
}
```

I also tried setting a timeout in the reducer with no success either.

```
case CLEAR_NOTIFICATION:
    const newData = state.data.filter(notification=>notification._id!==action.payload);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        return {
            ...state, 
            data: newData
        }}, 400);
```

I guess my question really boils down to a reverse setTimeout, where the function is called while the timeout is happening. Is there any way to solve this? Thanks!

Also, I have my animation in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Can you dispatch the action after the animation? Otherwise, your option would probably be something like `thunk` middleware and dispatching the action within setTimeout

Comment: I tried it but didn't work, anime js doesn't seem to stop the script while the animation plays out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually pretty simple, I just called the animation and set a timeout until the action was called:

```
handleDeleteNoti = notification => {
    anime({
        targets: this.notiRef,
        opacity: [1,0],
        duration: 500,
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{this.props.clearNotification(notification._id)}, 5000)
    // this.props.clearNotification(notification._id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve that by calling `clearNotification` after the timeout.

```
anime({targets: this.notiRef,opacity: [1,0],duration: 5000});
setTimeout(()=>{this.props.clearNotification(notification._id)}, 5000);
```

Also I recommend not using side effects in the reducer because that is an [anti-pattern](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions).